# UISearchController blocks UICollectionViewCell tap

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell, uisearchcontroller

I have a view controller with only one element inside - `UICollectionView`. This `UIViewController` is embedded in `UINavigationController`. In `viewDidLoad` method of this ViewController, I am initialising `UISearchController` and adding it to NavigationController. The problem is that whenever I try to search for something and I am currently entering the text in search bar, I need to tap 2 times on the `UICollectionViewCell` in order to trigger the tap. It looks like `UISearchController` is blocking the tap gesture of `UICollectionViewCell`. When I tap for the first time, the only thing that is happening is that "Cancel" button of the search bar is hiding. And then I need to tap another time to actually trigger the tap. I have tried many things to fix that, because I don't want the user having to tap 2 times on the cell instead of 1. These are the methods that I am calling in `viewDidLoad` method of this ViewController:

UISearchController initialisation:

```
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    definesPresentationContext = true
```

UICollectionView initialisation:

```
    self.collectionView?.delegate = self
    self.collectionView?.register(MyCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: MyCell.identifier)
    self.collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: collectionViewVerticalInset, left: collectionViewHorizontalInset, bottom: collectionViewVerticalInset, right: collectionViewHorizontalInset)
```

UICollectionView layout initialisation:

```
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = layout
    guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return }
```

UICollectionView data source initialisation:

```
    dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, MyEntity>(collectionView: collectionView) { (collectionView, indexPath, myEntity) -> UICollectionViewCell in
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyCell, for: indexPath) as! MyCell
        cell.setupCell(myEntity: MyEntity)
        return cell
    }
```

I didn't changed anything in UICollectionView inside the storyboard. Also this ViewController is presented modally.

Comment: Show a screenshot that tells what's hidden and what is not hidden.